# Android: WindowLeaked when rotate screen and dialog open

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog that is brought up when you click on an image in my activity. When the dialog is open and the user rotates the screen, the following is shown in my LogCat:

```
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589): Activity my.activity.MyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43554748 that was originally added here
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity my.activity.MyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43554748 that was originally added here
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at tip.machine.MyActivity$8.onClick(MyActivity.java:385)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-23 09:47:47.151: E/WindowManager(15589):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I did was declare the dialog globally by writing `Dialog dialog`, and in my `onPause`, I wrote this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    System.out.println("IN PAUSE!");
    try {
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("IN TRY!");
    }
    catch   (java.lang.NullPointerException exception)  {System.out.println("IN CATCH!");}
    super.onPause();
}
```

The catch block, I thought, would catch the error if `dialog` was not instantiated. Anyways, every time I rotate, whether or not the dialog is open, I enter the catch block only. When the dialog is open and I rotate, I get the same stack trace as above (it goes straight to the catch block). So it never even seems to attempt the `dialog.dismiss()` which is why I still get the `WindowLeaked` message.

Any ideas? Must be something wrong with my variable declaration/instantiation. Thanks.

Comment: I agree it must be something wrong with your variable declaration/instantiation. Can you please post that code?

Comment: @Samuel Got it, thanks. Please see my answer if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it. The problem was, I have two images which both use the same dialog variable (instantiate it when touched and launch their own dialogs). So the second image was referencing dialog by declaring it again as `final Dialog dialog ...`. I had it like that before I made `dialog` a global variable.

After removing the re-declaration, everything is perfect.

As an aside, is there any risk to using the same dialog variable for two different dialogs which can only be launched at separate times?

Comment: As long as you create a new instance each time they're used...no.  But if you're just hiding them to do any background processing after interaction or want to save their state, it could cause a problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are Screen changes landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape this reason **redraw** your view before redraw view you have to dismiss your dialog

so,
Try adding this attribute `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your Activity element in the AndroidManifest.xml file.